# How to evaluate the definite integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x\ln(\tan x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x\ln(\tan x)dx\space \text{?}$$

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x\ln(\tan x)dx$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}\right)\ln\left(\tan x\right)dx$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2\tan x\sec^2 x}{(1+\tan^2 x)^2}\ln\left(\tan x\right)dx$$
Let $\tan x=t\implies \sec^2 xdx=dt$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}\ln\left(t\right)dt$$

Any hint to proceed further or some easier method to solve this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

After working hard on the integral above, I found an easier way to solve.

Use the property of definite integral $\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx}$ as follows

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x \ln({\tan x}) dx\tag 1$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) \ln\left({\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}\right) dx$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x \ln\left({\cot x}\right) dx$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x \ln\left({\tan x}\right)^{-1} dx$$
$$\implies I=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2x \ln\left({\tan x}\right) dx\tag 2$$Adding the eq(1) & (2), we get 
$$2I=0$$ $$ \color{blue}{I=0}$$

Comment: Nice, yet you did this several hours after the last of the other answers is posted, so you at least knew the outcome . Anyway, good and helpful answers deserve your upvote.

Comment: A good solution indeed, thanks @Harish

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$$\sin(2x)\ln(\tan(x))=2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(\sin(x))-2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(\cos(x))$$

So your integral may be written as:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(\sin(x))dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(\cos(x))dx$$

Then use $u$-sub with $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in the first and second integrals.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way for the antiderivative first : change variable $t=\tan(x)$, $\sin(2x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$,$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}$. All of that makes $$I=\int\sin (2x)\log(\tan x)dx=\int\frac{ 2t }{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,\log (t)\, dt$$ Now, integration by parts $u=\log(t)$, $v'=\frac{ 2t }{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}dt$, $u'=\frac {dt}t$, $v=-\frac{1}{t^2+1}$ which make $$I=\int\frac{ 2t }{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,\log (t)\, dt=-\frac{\log (t)}{t^2+1}+\int\frac{dt}{t \left(t^2+1\right)}$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{1}{t \left(t^2+1\right)}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{t^2+1}$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Hi @Claude : when you substitute $\;t=\tan x\;$ , the new limits for the integral are $\;0\,,\,\,\infty\;$ , but then after integrating by parts you get $\;-\dfrac{\log t}{t^2+1}\;$ , and this has no finite limit when $\;t\to0^+\;$. Thus, either the substitution fails or the integration by parts does. I remark I did *not* check your work, just the outcome of it.

Comment: @Timbuc. After simplification, the antiderivative is $\frac{t^2 \log (t)}{t^2+1}-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(t^2+1\right)$ for which the limits are $0$ and $0$. But, I can be wrong, for sure.

Comment: But look at the middle of your answer: the value of your integral $\;I\;$ depends *also* in the value of $\;\left.-\dfrac{\log t}{t^2+1}\right|_0^\infty\;$ , and for this you need to pass to the limit when $\;t\to0^+\;$  which, if I'm not wrong, doesn't exist *finitely* . Am I missing something? That wouldn't be that odd, of course...

Comment: @Timbuc. I think that you are correct and that I have a problem. Thanks for pointing it ! Cheers :-(

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $I=I_1-I_2=\displaystyle \int2\sin x\cos x\ln(\sin x)dx - \displaystyle \int2\sin x\cos x \ln(\cos x)dx$. For $I_1$, let $t = \sin x$, and for $I_2$, let $t = \cos x$, and do integration by parts for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute

$$u=x-\frac\pi4\implies du=dx\implies$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2x\log\tan x\,dx=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)\log\tan\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)dx=$$

$$\int_{-\pi4}^{\pi/4}\cos2x\log\tan\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)dx$$

But the last integral's function, call it $\;g(x)\;$ , is an even function because $\;g(-x)=g(x)\;$ , since for $\;-\dfrac\pi4<x<\dfrac\pi4\;$ :

$$\log\tan\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)=-\log\tan\left(\frac\pi4+x\right)=\log\cot\left(\frac\pi4+x\right)\iff \tan\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)=\cot\left(\frac\pi4+x\right)$$

$$\iff \frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}=\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}\;\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

Thus, the integral, **in case it converges**, equals zero. I'll leave it to you to show your *improper* integral indeed converges (hint: use l'Hospital in both extremes to show those are removable discontinuities)

Answer (score 1):

Let $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x\ln(\tan x)dx$

Substitute $\displaystyle y = \frac{\pi}2-x$

$I = \displaystyle \int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{0}\sin 2(\frac{\pi}2 - y)\ln(\tan (\frac{\pi}2 - y))(-dy)\\ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin (\pi - 2y)\ln(\cot y)dy\\ =  \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2y\ln(\cot y)dy\\ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x\ln(\cot x)dx$

So $\displaystyle 2I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x(\ln(\tan x) + \ln(\cot x))dx\\ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x\ln(\tan x\cdot\cot x)dx\\ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x\ln 1\ dx = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin 2x \cdot 0\ dx\\ = \displaystyle 0 \\ \displaystyle \\ \therefore I = 0$

Comment: I did this independently and posted it without looking at the other answers, but I see it's very similar to the way the OP did it in his answer. There is a small variation in the last few steps, so I'm leaving it, for what it's worth. The method (subbing $x$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$) is always worth trying first for definite integrals of this form.

Answer (score 0):

The standard further substitution is $t^2=u$, $2tdt=du$,
$$
I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+u)^2} \ln \sqrt{u} du
=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+u)^2} \ln u du
$$
In general (Gradsteyn-Ryzhik 2.727.1)
$$
\int \frac{ \ln x}{(a+bx)^m}dx =\frac{1}{b(m-1)}\left[
-\frac{\ln x}{(a+bx)^{m-1}}+\int \frac{dx}{x(a+bx)^{m-1}}\right]
$$
and in particular
(Gradsteyn-Ryzhik 2.727.3)
$$
\int \frac{ \ln x}{(a+bx)^2}dx =
-\frac{\ln x}{b(a+bx)}+\frac{1}{ab}\ln\frac{x}{a+bx}.
$$
$$
\to
\int \frac{ \ln x}{(1+x)^2}dx =
-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\ln\frac{x}{1+x}.
$$
At the upper limit $\infty$ this expression converges to 0. At the lower limit
$$
I
=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0}
[-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\ln\frac{x}{1+x}]
=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0}
[-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\ln x-\ln(1+x)]
=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0} [-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\ln x]
$$
$$
=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0} [-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\frac{(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}]
=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\ln x}{1+x}
=-\frac12 \frac{0}{1+0}=0
$$

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this one by parts  as:
$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \sin { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right) dx= }  } $$ $$-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right) d\cos { 2x } = }  } $$ $$-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \cos { 2x } \frac { 2 }{ \sin { 2x }  } dx }  \right] =$$ $$ =-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-2\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { \cos { 2x }  }{ \sin { 2x }  } dx }  \right] $$ $$=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ x } -\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ \sin { x\cos { x }  }  } dx }  \right] =$$ $$=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \left( \frac { \cos { x }  }{ \sin { x }  } -\frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos { x }  }  \right) dx }  \right] $$ $$=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { d\sin { x }  }{ \sin { x }  } -\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { d\cos { x }  }{ \cos { x }  }  }  }  \right] $$ $$=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { \cos { 2x } \ln { \left( \tan { x }  \right)  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-{ \ln { \sin { x }  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }-{ \ln { \cos { x }  }  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \right] $$

Comment: Your last expression isn't seem to make sense because the evaluation of those expressions at those limits is *not* a finite number.